# Alamofire request with accent string in the responseJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm making a request with the following code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result{
            case .Success(let JSON):
            print (JSON as! NSDictionary)
```

the response is it:

```
   {
        guardado =     {
            email = "xxxxgopy@hotmail.com";
            id = 9552;
            name = "luz stella gonz\U00c3\U00a1lez";
            pwd = "*******";
        };
    }
```

How can I deal with the unicode characters \U00c3\U00a1.

When I tried to assign the value from the `name key` in a `String var` I'm getting this: ***luz stella gonzÃ¡lez***. But it could be **luz stella gonzález**

Comment: Error is on server side, encoding is wrong.

Comment: @EricAya if encoding is wrong, why when I make The request vía postman the response is good ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @Eric Aya says in the comments the problem was on the server side, the encoding was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let dictonary = ["email":"xxxxgopy@hotmail.com","id":9552,"pwd" :"*******","name":"luz stella gonz\u{00E1}lez"]
    print(dictonary)
   /* {
        email = "xxxxgopy@hotmail.com";
        id = 9552;
        name = "luz stella gonzález";
        pwd = "*******";
    }*/
```

encoding is wrong...